# Ray-Tracing inspired algorithm for sound reflection simulation

Tags: javascript

I am a civil architect by profession, with a passion for maths, physics and computers. For one of my projects, I am designing a room with 3 straight walls and 4th curved wall. A sound source is near the left wall.

```
+-------
|        \
| +       |
|        /
+-------
```

Having some spare time on my hands, I decided to try modeling the acoustics of this room using JavaScript and Canvas API. My goal was to calculate for every point in the room:

1. Net intensity of sound by summing sound coming directly from source and reflections off the walls (including curved one). This would include attenuation due to inverse square law and absorption by walls.
2. Reverb characteristics by keeping track of path lengths directly from source and reflections from walls. If a point in the room received reflected signal about 0.05 seconds after the primary signal arrives, we might have an echo problem.

I assumed a canvas size of 800x600 pixels and real world dimensions of the room as 45x44 feet (left wall = 44ft, top/bottom walls 31ft, curved wall radius 22ft) and sound source 5ft from left wall. I modeled each wall as a line or circle equation and wrote a function that tells me if a point is inside the room or not. For each pixel in the canvas, I convert it to a real world coordinate and calculate its distance from the source and use the inverse square law to calculate sound intensity. What I ended up was this:

[image]

However, needless to say, this only captures the primary bounce from the source. It doesn't capture any reflections and those are proving way too hard for me to calculate.

I'm looking for an insight into how I can do that. I have tried the following partially:

1. Instead of iterating points in the room grid-wise, I've tried to generate rays from the source. Calculating reflections off the straight walls is easy. But the curved wall presents some challenges. The biggest problem I'm having is this: If I start with 360 rays, the closest points to the source have way too many points per pixel, but as we move outwards, the points become so diluted that there may be tens of pixels between adjacent points. This also means that when I reflect a ray, it would most-certainly not land on the points created by the primary bounce and I wouldn't be able to simply add them up. Even if I interpolate, the result would not be correct as some points would register intensity due to primary bounce, even fewer would register intensity due to secondary/tertiary bounces, and many points would register nothing. In the image below, I've tried this approach with primary bounces only.

[image]

2. Iterate the room grid-wise. For each point in the room, calculate direct direction to the source and reflected location of source in each wall. Use these distances to calculate net intensity at every sample point in the room. This is easy to do for the straight walls. But the math turns EXTRAORDINARILY complicated and unsolvable for me for the curved wall.

```
               X
               +


                  +B
  +         +
  A         O
```

Assume `A` is the source, `O` is the center of curve, `B` is the point in room we're currently testing, and `X` is a point on the curve. For secondary bounces, ‹AXO = ‹BXO. We know `A`, `O` and `B`. If we can find `X`, then `BX` needs to be extended backwards a distance equal to `AX` and the image of the source would be located there. The problem is that finding `X` is a very hard problem. And even if this can be done, it only accounts for secondary bounces. Tertiary bounces would be even harder to calculate.

I believe Option #2 is the better way to go about this. But I do not possess enough math/computer skills to tackle this problem on my own. At this point in time, I'm trying to solve this not for my project, but for my personal curiosity. I would be grateful if any of you can solve this and share your solutions. Or if you can just give me insight into this problem, I would be glad to work on this further.

I lack expertise in computing interpolation and ray-tracing (which would be required for this problem, I think).

Thanks,
Asim

Comment: This is a interesting problem, an a well written question.  Unfortunately, it's not quite a valid question for SO, which expects you to be further along with a specific idea and confronting a programming problem within the bounds of that idea.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @danh. I understand your point and agree to what you say. For all of my past problems, I've done some research on google, then checked SO for existing answers, and only then post myself. I frankly don't know where to take this question elsewhere. It doesn't suit MathOverflow since the problem is of programming primarily, where you represent real-world environment and have to map it to pixels of finite size.. Mathematically, the problem is somewhat solvable.. Programmatically, it's giving me nightmares. If I wasn't curious enough, I'd probably even let it slip.. =)

Comment: Notice I didn't vote to close.  :-)  On the problem, consider that pixels is an arbitrary unit. I imagine, to model sound that impacts a human ear, you should care about something like 3" squares.  How many pixels is that?  It depends on how large your picture is.  Try to think about the problem independent of the visualization.  A 12x12 foot room divided into 3"x3" squares makes a 48x48 grid.  I think your job is to pick an angular granularity (not 1 deg... also arbitrary) so that each far wall grid cell can be hit by at least on ray from the source.

Comment: Then (and I've never done any ray tracing), my first thought is to model that many rays emanating from the source, follow each ray through several bounces, reducing its energy as you go, and accumulating its energy in each cell that it passes through.  Consider it a separate (but very doable) job to render that array of cell energies on a canvas.

Comment: I think that makes sense. Thanks for the heads up. I'll try to work on this approach and report back when I have something tangible. :-) and thanks for not voting to close. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So. With great pointers from lara and a deep dive into matrix math and bresenham's line rendering algorithms, I was finally able to complete this hobby project. =) Outlined here are the steps for anyone wishing to follow down this route for similar problems.

1. Ditch algebraic equations in favor of matrix math. Ditch lines in favor of parametric lines.
2. Represent walls in terms of rays and circles. Lines can be represented as `[x y 1] = [x0 y0 1] + t*[dx dy 1]`. Circles can be represented as `(X - C)^2 = r^2`.
3. Project rays outwards from the source. For each ray, calculate its intersection with one of the walls, and resize it to span from its starting point to the intersection point.
4. When an intersection point is calculated, calculate the normal vector of the wall at the point of intersection. For straight walls, calculating normal is simple (`[-dy dx 1]`). For circles, the normal is `X - C`.
5. Use matrices to reflect the incident ray about the normal.
6. Repeat the process for as many bounces as needed.
7. Map the World Coordinate System the plan is in to a Cell Coordinate System to divide the world into a grid of cells. Each cell can be 1'-0" x 1'-0" in size (in feet). Use matrices again for transformation between the two coordinate systems.
8. Use the transformation matrix to convert the ray to the Cell Coordinate System.
9. Use Bresemham's Line algorithm to determine which cells the ray passes thru. For each cell, use the inverse square law to calculate ray intensity for that cell. Add this value to the cells grid.
10. Finally, use Canvas API and another transformation matrix to convert between Cell Coordinate System to Screen Coordinate System and render the cells grid on screen.

Here are a few screenshots of what I achieved using this:

[image: 1]
Rays of light emanating from the source and intersecting with the walls.

[image: 2]
Calculating multiple reflections of a single ray.

[image: 3]
Calculating single reflections of all rays emanating from the source.

[image: 4]
Using Bresenham's Line algorithm to identify cells crossed by the ray and plotting logarithmic intensity.

[image: 5]
Rendering all cells for all primary rays only.

[image: 6]
Rendering all cells for reflected rays only. The caustic surface is clearly visible here.

[image: 7]
Rendering all cells for primary and reflected rays using color-coding.

I got to learn a lot of very interesting math skills during the course of this project. I respect matrices a lot more now. All during my college years, I wondered if I would ever need to use the Bresenham's Line algorithm ever in my life, since all graphics libraries have line drawing algorithms build-in. For the first time, I found that I needed to directly use this algorithm and without it, this project would not have been possible.

I will make available the code on GitHub soon. Thanks to everyone who contributed to my understanding of these concepts.

Asim